# How do I get a handle for the current workbench in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing my first plug-in for eclipse. My view works perfectly fine independently. The problem occurs when I try to get an instance of the view. When I searched online, I found that we can get the view by invoking `Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getViewRegistry()`. But `Activator.getDefault()` is returning null.

I have checked that in my plug-in's manifest file, the option 'Activate this plugin when one of the classes is loaded' is checked and 'Bundle-ActivationPolicy' is lazy.

Since I had no luck with '`Activator.getDefault()`', I tried another approach: to get the workbench by calling `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()`. But I get the famous '`Workbench has not been activated yet`' message. I thought I will have to wait till the workbench is created and so tried `while(!PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()){}` but it never got past this loop.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you running this code? It sounds like you are calling it from the wrong place

Comment: I want to interact with my view from a normal java program. So I wrote a small program test.java and called PlatformUI.getWorkbench() method from the main method in this class.

Comment: You can not access an Eclipse workbench from a normal Java program. It must be an Eclipse plugin or a complete Eclipse RCP (which can be 'headless' - no GUI)